# List of Column names having at least 1 Null value and total number of null values corresponding to each column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, null

Hi I have a code which prints column names along with null values in columns:

```
A    B     C    D
1    1     4    NAN
2    2     5     NAN
3    NAN   6     NAN
```

**My Code**

```
[IN]res = list(df.isnull().sum().items())
[IN]print(res)
```

**Current Output**

```
[('A', 0), ('B', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 3)]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[('B', 1), ('D', 3)]
```

So basically I wish to remove columns where there are 0 null values and **return only columns with at least 1 null value.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.isnull().sum()
res = list(s[s > 0].items())
print (res)
[('B', 1), ('D', 3)]
```

Or filter using [`callable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
res = list(df.isnull().sum()[lambda x: x > 0].items())
```

Or filter in list comprehension:

```
res = [(k, v) for k, v in df.isnull().sum().items() if v > 0]
```